# How do I know when a tab bar item is pressed (iOS)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, uikit

I have 2 view controllers and a tab bar controller created in storyboard.

is it possible to execute a method in either of the 2 view controllers when the relevant tab bar is pressed?

Ive tried several ways but they need a nib name on the firstViewController or secondViewController if I want to initialize an object of the firstViewController, normally the firstViewController is just created on launch,

Any help would be appreciated, I'm vaguely familiar with the uitabcontroller app delegate but I don't know how to hook up the two view controllers to the tab controller

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the `UITabViewController Delegate` :

> You use the **UITabBarControllerDelegate** protocol when you want to
>   augment the behavior of a tab bar. In particular, you can use it to
>   determine whether specific tabs should be selected, to perform actions
>   after a tab is selected, or to perform actions before or after the
>   user customizes the order of the tabs. After implementing these
>   methods in your custom object, you should then assign that object to
>   the delegate property of the corresponding **UITabBarController** object.
>
> All of the methods in this protocol are optional.

**Reference :** http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

---

What you need should be achievable by implementing :

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController 
 didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using storyboard, do this

in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
UITabBarController *tabBar = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
[tabBar setDelegate:self];
```

And then

```
-(void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
   //Write your code here
}
```